# How can I find correct XPath

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to scrape data from a website, but I'm getting the following error.

```
        string testurl = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202110190MIL.html";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(testurl);

        var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"div_four_factors\"]");

        int nodeCt = htmlNodes.Count;
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

This is a snippet from the Page Source:

```
<div class="table_container" id="div_four_factors">

<table class="suppress_all stats_table" id="four_factors" data-cols-to-freeze=",1">
<caption>Four Factors Table</caption>
```

```
  <tr class="over_header">
     <th aria-label="" data-stat="" colspan="2" class=" over_header center" ></th>
     <th aria-label="" data-stat="header_tmp" colspan="4" class=" over_header center" >Four Factors</th><th></th>
  </tr>
        
  <tr>
     <th aria-label="&nbsp;" data-stat="team_id" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc left" data-tip="Team" >&nbsp;</th>
     <th aria-label="Pace Factor" data-stat="pace" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="<b>Pace Factor</b>: An estimate of possessions per 48 minutes" >Pace</th>
     <th aria-label="Effective Field Goal Percentage" data-stat="efg_pct" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="<strong>Effective Field Goal Percentage</strong><br>This statistic adjusts for the fact that a 3-point field goal is worth one more point than a 2-point field goal." data-over-header="Four Factors" >eFG%</th>
     <th aria-label="Turnover Percentage" data-stat="tov_pct" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc right" data-tip="<b>Turnover Percentage</b><br>An estimate of turnovers committed per 100 plays." data-over-header="Four Factors" >TOV%</th>
     <th aria-label="Offensive Rebound Percentage" data-stat="orb_pct" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="<b>Offensive Rebound Percentage</b><br>An estimate of the percentage of available offensive rebounds a player grabbed while they were on the floor." data-over-header="Four Factors" >ORB%</th>
     <th aria-label="FT/FGA" data-stat="ft_rate" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="Free Throws Per Field Goal Attempt" data-over-header="Four Factors" >FT/FGA</th>
     <th aria-label="Offensive Rating" data-stat="off_rtg" scope="col" class=" poptip right" data-tip="<b>Offensive Rating</b><br>An estimate of points produced (players) or scored (teams) per 100 possessions" >ORtg</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
```

[BRK](/teams/BRK/2022.html)101.8.54211.310.9.155102.1
[MIL](/teams/MIL/2022.html)101.8.5385.825.0.133124.7

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but I have resorted to using Regex  to get a work-around.:)

Comment: Your question is not stating the facts correctly, specifically regarding the page source. Download the source code ot the page with the URL in your code example. Look for the `id="div_four_factors"` attribute. You will notice that it appears only **inside a <!-- ... --> comment block**. Therefore there is no HTML element with an `id="div_four_factors"` attribute on that page. Just a comment that, among other text, contains the text sequence `id="div_four_factors"`. No surprise that HtmlAgilityPack can't find an element with such attribute, because there is none to be found.

Comment: `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml` does not fetch data from a URL. [You should use `HtmlWeb.Load`](https://html-agility-pack.net/from-web)

Comment: LoadHtml seems to be loading a string that is HTML but doesn't execute a request to fetch it from a URL. I checked the source code it seems the div id you are looking for is actually commented out.

Comment: The "//*[@id=\"four_factors\"]" is the XPath I get when I Inspect the element using Firefox Developer.  Here is the Regex Pattern I have used to get it to work with Regex  string Pattern = "<table class=\"suppress_all stats_table\"(.*?)</table>";  And looking at the page source, the text I want to scrape are not in the commented section.  How do I test with that "NetFiddle" thingy?

Comment: I see it is in a commented section when I view the page source.  I don't know why my Inspect element on the web page gives me the incorrect XPath.  I'm seeing it using multiple browsers.  Chrome, Firefox

Comment: Don't use a web browser to inspect page source. Because this will not necessarily show you the page as downloaded from the server. A page can be dynamically altered by Javascript in the browser to such a degree that its HTML "code" might look entirely different from the original pure downloaded page source. HtmlAgilityPack (and other HTML processors) are NOT web browsers and don't function like web browsers. Most importantly, they don't execute Javascript and process the HTML document as it is in its original unmodified form. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Hence why you should not use web browsers to inspect the page HTML, because you never know if they show you the original page source or the page altered by Javascript...

Comment: MySkul, What do you use to get the XPATH if not a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element you're looking for is within a comment block in the page **source** (i.e. not the rendered HTML) it's a little more tricky.

First you need to find the comment, get the contents of it and parse it as HTML:

```cs
string testurl = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202110190MIL.html";
        
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(testurl);
        
var comment = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
    // Get all comments.
    // If you know where the comment is you can optimize this XPath:
    .SelectNodes("//comment()")
    // Only get the one(s) with the element you're looking for
    .Where(c => c.OuterHtml.Contains("div_four_factors"))
    .First(); // In this example I assume there's only one
        
// Remove comment characters: "<!--" and "-->"
var commentContent = comment.OuterHtml[4..^3];
// Load the HTML within the comment
var commentDoc = new HtmlDocument();
commentDoc.LoadHtml(commentContent);

// Find your node
var htmlNodes = commentDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"div_four_factors\"]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the LoadFromBrowser also works. Here is the code I am using.

```
//***********Load FRom Browser

        string[] result1 = new string[] { };

        HtmlWeb web1 = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc1 = web1.LoadFromBrowser(url, html =>
        {
            // Wait for the HTML element to exist
            return !html.Contains("//*[@id=\"div_four_factors\"]");
        });

        var _extractText = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"div_four_factors\"]").InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(_extractText);
```